# Hard-coded 'require' from a racket macro doesn't bind 'provided' identifiers

Tags: macros, racket, require

I'm struggling to understand what is conceptually different between these two simple macros that is causing the `import-bad` version to fail with 'unbound identifier' errors.

imports-mod.rkt exports `myid`:

```
#lang racket/base
(provide myid)
(define (myid x)x)
(displayln "imported mod")
```

imports.rkt defines the macros that `require "imports-mod.rkt"`, and tries to use `import-bad`:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse racket/syntax))

(define-syntax (import-good stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ mod-id:string)
     (define s (syntax/loc stx (require mod-id)))
     (displayln s)
     s]
    [else #'(displayln "no")]))


(define-syntax (import-bad stx)
  #'(require "imports-mod.rkt"))


(import-bad "imports-mod.rkt")
(myid 123)
;; ^^^ This results in ` myid: unbound identifier in: myid`
```

It works if `import-good` is used instead.

Examining the expansion through the macro stepper for `import-good` and `import-bad` shows that they appear to expand to the same code: `(require "imports-mod.rkt")`

But something *must* be different about them, and I suspect this is to do with the `mod-id` template variable having some special property that I'm missing.

If I *just* use `import-bad`, without trying to call `myid`, I see the output `imported mod` which comes from `imports-mod.rkt`. So it is actually loading the module, just not binding the `myid` identifier.

Comment: Using `(define-syntax (import-bad stx) (datum->syntax stx '(require "imports-mod.rkt")))` works too. I'm not sure, but I *think* the literal in your version isn't working because of something to do with lexical context. Might have better luck asking on the [Racket Discourse forum](https://racket.discourse.group/)

Comment: My hunch about the context was correct; the code in that question is more complicated, but same basic issue and same suggestion to use `datum->syntax`

Comment: Shawn: that's great thanks! I must have overlooked datum->syntax as being the same as syntax/loc - which it's clearly not. I've just accepted the suggested answer, but thank you so much - it was a massive help!